# How to call an Oracle function with a Ref Cursor as Out-parameter from C#?

Tags: oracle, function, odp.net, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

I'm using a product that provides a database API based on Oracle functions and I'm able to call functions via ODP.NET in general. However, I can't figure out, how to call a function that includes a Ref Cursor as Out-parameter. All the samples I found so far either call a procedure with Out-parameter or a function with the Ref Cursor as return value. I tried to define the parameters similiarly, but keep getting the error that the wrong number or type of parameters is supplied.

Here is the function header (obviously obfuscated):

```
FUNCTION GetXYZ(
   uniqueId       IN   somepackage.Number_Type,
   resultItems    OUT  somepackage.Ref_Type)
   RETURN somepackage.Error_Type;
```

These are the type definitions in "somepackage":

```
SUBTYPE Number_Type IS NUMBER(13);
TYPE Ref_Type IS REF CURSOR;
SUBTYPE Error_Type IS NUMBER;
```

And this is the code that I have tried:

```
string sql = "otherpackage.GetXYZ";
var getXYZCmd = OracleCommand oracleConnection.CreateCommand(sql);
getXYZCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

getXYZCmd.Parameters.Add("uniqueId", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = uniqueExplosionId;
getXYZCmd.Parameters.Add("resultItems", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getXYZCmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

The I tried the following different ways to call the function (of course only one at a time):

```
var result = getXYZCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var reader = getXYZCmd.ExecuteReader();
var scalarResult = getXYZCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But each of them fails with the error message:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETXYZ'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETXYZ'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
```

So is it generally possible to call a function with a Ref Cursor as Out-parameter from C# with ODP.NET? I can call a function with the same structure with a Varchar2-Out-parameter instead of the Ref Cursor without problems...

Btw, I'm using ODP.NET version 2.112.2.0 from C#.NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You sure can.  There are a few gotchas to be wary of but here is a test case

```
create or replace function testodpRefCursor(
                  uniqueId    IN NUMBER 
                 ,resultItems OUT NOCOPY SYS_REFCURSOR) RETURN NUMBER
                 IS

 BEGIN
      OPEN resultItems for select level from dual  connect by level < uniqueId ;
      return 1;
 END testodpRefCursor;
```

1. I have found that
   functions likes to have the
   ReturnValue as [**THE FIRST**](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=387950&tstart=0) param
   in the collection
2. BindByName is by default FALSE, so it defaults to BIND BY POSITION

Otherwise it is quite straight forward:

```
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("TESTODPREFCURSOR", con);
  cmd.CommandType   = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.BindByName = true;
  // Bind 


  OracleParameter oparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.Int64);
  oparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue ;       

  OracleParameter oparam0 = cmd.Parameters.Add("uniqueId", OracleDbType.Int64);
  oparam0.Value = 5 ;
  oparam0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

  OracleParameter oparam1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("resultItems", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
  oparam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;




  // Execute command
  OracleDataReader reader;
  try
  {
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read() ){
        Console.WriteLine("level: {0}", reader.GetDecimal(0));  
    }

  } ...
```

Now for more samples go to your Oracle Home directory and look @ the Ref cursor samples in ODP.NET

for instance:
%oracle client home%\odp.net\samples\4\RefCursor

hth

Comment: thanks for providing the samples directory. you've saved the day:]