# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option When trying to execute PL/SQL from C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am almost positive this is user error.

I am new to connecting C# to an Oracle database and have modeled my code after that in the [Oracle online documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featRefCursor.htm)

My PL/SQL works from within Oracle SQL Developer. The error I am getting in my test.aspx page is:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

The code behind in the test.aspx.cs page is:

```
string currentTerm = getCurrentTerm();
    string passwd = "<get password input>";
    string salt = "<get salted input>";

    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTIONSTRINGNAME"].ConnectionString;

        conn.Open();

        // pl/sql block
        string pl_sql = "  set serveroutput on " +
                                    "DECLARE"+
                                    "   output                 tablename.function%TYPE;" +
                                    "BEGIN"+
                                    "   tablename.myfunction(:1,:2,:3);" +
                                    "   dbms_output.put_line('output= '||output"+
                                    "END;";

        //Oracle Parameters necessary for the myfunction function
        OracleParameter p_1 = new OracleParameter(passwd, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, ParameterDirection.Input);
        OracleParameter p_2 = new OracleParameter(salt, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, ParameterDirection.Input);
        OracleParameter p_3 = new OracleParameter("3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, ParameterDirection.Output);

        // create the command object
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = pl_sql;

        // add the parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_3);

        // execute the pl/sql block
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // get a data reader from the ref cursor 
        //    note: this is on p_3, the output value
        OracleDataReader dr = ((OracleRefCursor)p_3.Value).GetDataReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            Response.Write("Salt licked hash: "+ dr[0].ToString());
            //Output the line retrieved from dbms_output.put line
            Response.Write("<br />");
            Response.Write("DBMS_OUTPUT STATUS: "+ p_3.Value.ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is a SQL*Plus function-- it is not part of the SQL or PL/SQL language (though lots of GUIs like SQL Developer and Toad have at least some support for SQL*Plus functions like this).

2) You almost certainly do not want to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` for anything having to do with your application-- that's not the right way to get data from a PL/SQL block.  Technically, you could call `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(<<buffer size>>)` in your PL/SQL block, write data to the buffer using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` and then have your application make calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` to read the data from the buffer once the procedure completed.  That's what SQL*Plus and SQL Developer are doing under the covers.  But that's not the appropriate way to structure an application.

3) I'm not sure what type `tablename.myfunction` is returning.  If it is returning a simple scalar or a REF CURSOR, life is much easier-- you can just call the function without the PL/SQL anonymous block as Harrison demonstrates in [this SO thread on calling a function that returns a REF CURSOR in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360244/how-to-call-an-oracle-function-with-a-ref-cursor-as-out-parameter-from-c).  If it is returning a PL/SQL record type, Mark Williams has an example of [an anonymous PL/SQL block that returns a PL/SQL record in C#](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=329643) on the OTN forums.

Comment: tablename.myfunction returns Varchar2  Made your suggested changes and get a new error...I think that is good. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "REDACTED_TABLE", line 77 ORA-06512: at "REDACTED_TABLE", line 130 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @user834436 - Assuming that `REDACTED_TABLE` is a function name, what is at line 130 and line 77?

Comment: Oh, I guess it is a function not a table.  Quick question, could this now just be a permissions issue?  If so, why does it work with SQL Developer and not with the code from C#?

Comment: @user834346 - The third parameter is an OUT parameter.  In your original code, you were passing a 50 character buffer.  Are you sure that buffer is large enough?

Comment: Funny you should mention that.  I was looking through the documentation and saw they are using 2000 so I changed my code to this:`code`//Oracle Parameters necessary for the myfunction function
            OracleParameter p_1 = new OracleParameter(passwd, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input);
            OracleParameter p_2 = new OracleParameter(salt, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Input);
            OracleParameter p_3 = new OracleParameter(output, OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Output);

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you closing this statement `dbms_output.put_line('output= '||output"+`

Comment: Good point. That didn't fix it though. Same error. It completes successfully in Oracle SQL Developer