# Can Oracle Ref Cursors only be used with Procedures and Functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, odp.net

Can Oracle Ref Cursors only be used with Procedures and Functions, or can they also be used with PL/SQL issued via an ODP.NET OracleCommand object (contained as a string in the CommandText property)?

Comment: Procedures and Functions _are_ PL/SQL. Cursors can be used in any Pl/SQL block, i.e. a `begin ... end;`

Comment: Yeah, no doubt they _are_ PL/SQL, I'm just trying to find out if Ref Cursors are restricted to use with them, which I believe the 2nd half of your comment answers.  I've up-voted your comment, since it won't let me check it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

You can certainly execute an anonymous PL/SQL block from a .Net or a Java application that internally makes use of a `REF CURSOR`.  Since anonymous PL/SQL blocks do not accept or return parameters, however, you cannot return a `REF CURSOR` that you open in an anonymous PL/SQL block to the calling application.

From an application architecture standpoint, I would strongly advocate that if you need to do processing that requires PL/SQL, that processing ought to be incorporated into a named PL/SQL block (a procedure or a function) that is in a package and stored in the database.  Having logic implemented in PL/SQL that is stored outside the database is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I thought the anonymous PL/SQL could return data via output bind variables/parameters in ODP.NET, is that not the case with Ref Cursors?    I can appreciate that it is a bad idea to be placed outside the database, unfortunately that decision is out of my hands.

Comment: @Paul - I don't believe that is possible with a `REF CURSOR`.  Obviously, I'd welcome someone pointing out a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: It would seem it's possible with a stored function (e.g. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360244/how-to-call-an-oracle-function-with-a-ref-cursor-as-out-parameter-from-c]), but as far as I can determine, you are correct, it is not possible with anonymous PL/SQL.

Comment: Good news for anyone who reads this later.  In a related question, @Juergen-Hartelt just showed the way to use a Ref Cursor as an output bind variable/parameter with an anonymous PL/SQL command used via C# with ODP.NET (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267746/how-to-use-an-oracle-ref-cursor-from-c-sharp-odp-net-as-a-returnvalue-parameter).