# Returning cursor from PL/SQL anonymous block in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql, odp.net

I'm working on converting an existing application from SQL Server over to Oracle, and I've hit a roadblock. I'm trying to execute an anonymous block as dynamic SQL and return a result set. However nothing I've tried seems to be able to return any values. Stored procedures are out due to design constraints.

My query is defined as:

```
DECLARE type id_array IS TABLE OF number;
t_Ids id_array;
BEGIN
UPDATE CSM_RECORDS SET MIGRATION_STATE = 1, LAST_UPDATE = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE OBJECT_UID IN 
(SELECT OBJECT_UID 
FROM CSM_RECORDS obj 
WHERE MIGRATION_STATE = 0
AND ROWNUM <= :BatchSize)
AND (:BatchName IS NULL OR obj.BATCH_NAME = :BatchName)
RETURNING OBJECT_UID BULK COLLECT INTO t_Ids;

OPEN rcursor FOR SELECT * FROM CSM_RECORDS;-- WHERE OBJECT_UID IN (t_Ids);
END;
```

You can see I've commented out the WHERE clause on the cursor in an attempt just to get *anything* to return at all.

Over on the C# side, I've got:

```
OracleCommand getNextNodesC = new OracleCommand(SQL_AS_SHOWN_ABOVE, conn);
getNextNodesC.BindByName = true;

OracleParameter batchSizeP = new OracleParameter("BatchSize", OracleDbType.Int32);
batchSizeP.Value = batchSize;

getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(batchSizeP);

OracleParameter batchNameP = new OracleParameter("BatchName", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
batchNameP.Value = batchName;

getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(batchNameP);


OracleParameter returnCursor = new OracleParameter("rcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
returnCursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(returnCursor);

getNextNodesC.ExecuteNonQuery();

return ((Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)returnCursor.Value).GetDataReader();
```

The end goal is a `DbDataReader` that I can use, but in the above code, the `returnCursor.Value` seems to remain null. I've tried various combinations of `Output` vs. `ReturnValue` parameters and `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteReader()` to no avail.

Any pointers would be appreciated, but an example of code that would actually accomplish what I'm looking for would be spectacular.

Comment: Where is your code after `OPEN CURSOR`. `OPEN Cursor` will only set the cursor and make it ready to be read from, it will not return any data back to the caller

Comment: How would I go about returning data back to the caller then?  There's a good chance that's my problem.  I've tried doing a `RETURN rcursor;` right after the `OPEN...` line, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Try bind by position to take that out of the picture, also see the ref cursor example code in the odp.net samples directory in your oracle home.

Comment: ..also greatly simplify the sql so you are guaranteed some rows will come back (get rid of the nested select)

Comment: Binding by position results in a `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CURSER` error.  I can't tell if that's a step closer, or a step further from a solution.
Edit: I actually commented out the entire WHERE clause (see above) in the cursor statement to guarantee I should be getting something back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback everyone.  It turns out that while debugging this issue, at some point I switched out the variable that defined my query, so that changes I was making to the query weren't actually being applied when running the application.  As a result, I'm not sure exactly which fix ended up being the answer.  But just for completeness, here's what I ended up using that worked.

First, run:

```
create type id_array as table of number;
```

(From answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267746/how-to-use-an-oracle-ref-cursor-from-c-sharp-odp-net-as-a-returnvalue-parameter))

Query:

```
DECLARE t_Ids id_array;
BEGIN
UPDATE CSM_RECORDS SET MIGRATION_STATE = 1, LAST_UPDATE = CURRENT_DATE
    WHERE OBJECT_UID IN 
    (SELECT OBJECT_UID 
    FROM CSM_RECORDS obj 
    WHERE MIGRATION_STATE = 0
    AND ROWNUM <= :BatchSize
    AND (:BatchName IS NULL OR obj.BATCH_NAME = :BatchName)
RETURNING OBJECT_UID BULK COLLECT INTO t_Ids;

OPEN :rcursor FOR SELECT * FROM CSM_RECORDS WHERE OBJECT_UID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(cast(t_Ids as id_array)));
END;
```

And the C# looks like:

```
OracleCommand getNextNodesC = new OracleCommand(QUERY_DEFINED_ABOVE.Replace("\r\n", "\n"), conn);

getNextNodesC.BindByName = true;

OracleParameter batchSizeP = new OracleParameter("BatchSize", OracleDbType.Int32);
batchSizeP.Value = batchSize;
getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(batchSizeP);

OracleParameter batchNameP = new OracleParameter("BatchName", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
batchNameP.Value = batchName;
getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(batchNameP);

OracleParameter returnCursor = new OracleParameter("rcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
returnCursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
getNextNodesC.Parameters.Add(returnCursor);

return getNextNodesC.ExecuteReader();
```

b_levitt's suggestion about the missing colon on the cursor bind variable was spot-on though.  And I also needed to replace all the "\r\n"s in my query with "\n".

I'm still not clear on why I need to run `CREATE TYPE...` rather than just using `DECLARE TYPE...` since the latter seems to work fine for the `BULK COLLECT` part of the block, but it does seem to work fine now.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: You're missing the colon on your cursor bind variable:

```
OPEN :rcursor FOR SELECT * FROM CSM_RECORDS;-- WHERE OBJECT_UID IN (t_Ids);
```

Full answer:
As you probably know, in oracle there is the pl/sql context (your anonymous block) and the SQLplus context.  Here is a block with SQLplus vars, the block with the related bind variables, and a SQLplus print at the end:

```
var rcursor refcursor
var fromDate varchar2(50)
var toDate varchar2(50)
exec :fromDate := '1-mar-2014';
exec :toDate := '1-apr-2014';

begin
  open :rcursor for
    SELECT
     trunc(to_date(:fromDate,'dd-mon-yyyy')) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day') AS Full_Date
    FROM (
    select (level-1) n
    from dual
    connect by level-1 <= trunc(to_date(:toDate,'dd-mon-yyyy')) - trunc(to_date(:fromDate,'dd-mon-yyyy'))
   )
  ;
end;
/
print rcursor
```

When executing a block in .net, ODP.net is taking care of the preparation done at the SQLplus level.  Here is the same block executed from .net (as an nunit test):

```
[Test]
public void RefCursorFromBatch()
{
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = @"
  begin
    open :rcursor for
      SELECT
       trunc(to_date(:fromDate,'dd-mon-yyyy')) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day') AS Full_Date
      FROM (
      select (level-1) n
      from dual
      connect by level-1 <= trunc(to_date(:toDate,'dd-mon-yyyy')) - trunc(to_date(:fromDate,'dd-mon-yyyy'))
     )
    ;
  end;";
  cmd.BindByName = true;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("fromDate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("toDate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("rcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection("..."))
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    Assert.Greater(dt.Rows.Count, 0);

  }
}
```

You can read more here: http://www.brothersincode.com/post/executing-SQL-Plus-Batches-from-Net.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to execute the SP in the similar way? e.g. @" EXECUTE My_PROC(:Param1,:Param2, :Param3);" and Param3 is and output parameter in My_Proc

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have an answer yet, here is some example code that I have confirmed is working, that you can use as a starting point.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Class1
  {

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      { 
        string conString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=orcl;Pooling=false;";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = conString;
        con.Open();

        string cmdtxt = "BEGIN " +
          "OPEN :1 for select ename, deptno from emp where deptno = 10; " +
          "OPEN :2 for select ename, deptno from emp where deptno = 20; " +
          "OPEN :3 for select ename, deptno from emp where deptno = 30; " +
          "END;";

        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = cmdtxt;

        OracleParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor1",
            OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        OracleParameter p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor2",
            OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        OracleParameter p3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor3",
            OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        p3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        OracleDataReader dr1 =
          ((OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters[2].Value).GetDataReader();
        OracleDataReader dr2 =
          ((OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters[1].Value).GetDataReader();


        while (dr1.Read() && dr2.Read())
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + dr1.GetString(0) + ", " +
              "Employee Dept:" + dr1.GetDecimal(1));
          Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + dr2.GetString(0) + ", " +
              "Employee Dept:" + dr2.GetDecimal(1));
          Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();


      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your dynamic sql...

```
DECLARE type id_array IS TABLE OF number;
t_Ids id_array;
BEGIN
UPDATE CSM_RECORDS SET MIGRATION_STATE = 1, LAST_UPDATE = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE OBJECT_UID IN 
(SELECT OBJECT_UID 
FROM CSM_RECORDS obj 
WHERE MIGRATION_STATE = 0
AND ROWNUM <= :BatchSize)
RETURNING OBJECT_UID BULK COLLECT INTO t_Ids;

SELECT * FROM CSM_RECORDS;-- WHERE OBJECT_UID IN (t_Ids);
END;
```

Comment: No dice.  No errors, but `returnCursor.Value` is still null.  Trying `ExecuteReader()` still returns a reader with no rows.