# How to execute pl sql block using oledb in c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, plsql

I am executing Pl/Sql block using OLEDB in C#.
The code is:

```
        string a1;
        a1 = discom1.Text.ToString();

        my_querry10 = "BEGIN"+
                      "SELECT * from MasterCompliant WHERE Discom ='" + a1 + "';"+
                      "" + var1 + " = SQL%ROWCOUNT;"+
                      "END;";
        OleDbCommand cmd12 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry10, conn);
        conn.Open();

        cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The exception is coming to statement:

> "cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery" as
>    "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."

MasterCompliant is table name; Discom is column name and var1 is integer.

Comment: Well your string starts with `BEGINSTART` - not a great starting point. You're also putting your parameters directly into your SQL string, which is a *really bad idea*. Use parameterized SQL instead. Do you really *need* to execute a block instead of just one command? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: My task is: i am searching the string 'a1' from Discom column name and trying to retrieve its count in integer 'var1' using SQL&ROWCOUNT..

Comment: This block will not work as intended even if you correct the syntax errors. You're executing a `SELECT` statement where you should open a cursor. Furthermore, you're attempting to assign `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to C# variable `var1` from inside a PL/SQL block - this won't work as PL/SQL has no knowledge of your C# (or VB or whatever) variables. (And - use the assignment operator `:=`). Please - have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821112/returning-cursor-from-pl-sql-anonymous-block-in-c-sharp) which shows HOW to get values back from an anonymous block. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't need a separate block for this at all - you can just use `SELECT COUNT(1)` and `ExecuteScalar`:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MasterCompliant WHERE Discom = ?";
int count;

// Open and close a connection each time you need one - let the connection pool
// handle making that efficient.
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@v", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = discom1.Text;
        count = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

It's possible that you need to cast to `long` instead of `int` - you should basically try it and see.

Note how using a parameterized query makes the SQL simpler to read *and* prevents [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon near `a1`

`Discom ='" + a1 + "';"+` to   `Discom ='" + a1 + "'"+`

```
"BEGIN"+
"SELECT * from MasterCompliant WHERE Discom ='" + a1 + "'"+
"" + var1 + " = SQL%ROWCOUNT;"+
"END;"
```

Comment: Its not working.. similar exception even after removing the semicolon.