# Creating methods for making Generic DB calls

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am trying to write some methods which should be DB independent, so that the same code can be used irrespective of DB (Oracle, SQL server)

I am using IDbConnection and IDbCommand interfaces for this..
While calling the procedure it gives error saying Illegal Variable name/number error. Though I am able to call the inline query directly(Directly specifying the query as the command Text)
Here is the sample call..

```
using (IDbConnection connection = this._providerFactory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    // create the command object using the conneciton object
                    IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    //start
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "GetResponse";

                   IDbDataParameter menuParam = this._providerFactory.CreateParameter();
                   menuParam.DbType = DbType.String;
                   menuParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                   menuParam.ParameterName = "@V_USER_ID";
                   command.Parameters.Add(menuParam);

                   IDbDataParameter menuParam2 = this._providerFactory.CreateParameter();
                   menuParam2.Size = 20;

                   menuParam2.DbType = DbType.String;
                   menuParam2.Size = 20;
                   menuParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                   menuParam2.ParameterName = "@V_ROLE_ID";
                   menuParam2.Value = DBNull.Value;
                   command.Parameters.Add(menuParam2);
                    //end



                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No value is being supplied here (and drop the @ symbol):

```
             IDbDataParameter menuParam = this._providerFactory.CreateParameter(); 
               menuParam.DbType = DbType.String; 
               menuParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
               menuParam.ParameterName = "V_USER_ID"; 
               command.Parameters.Add(menuParam);
```

Comment: @Nits - updated my answer.. you're not providing a value for the first param.

Comment: still no luck :( getting the same error ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: that is working actually, but again when the OUT parameter in proc is REf_Cursor it doesn't work. I am using menuParam2.DbType = DbType.Object;  As did not geother option like Cursor

Comment: Not sure on the cursor... read this post, they use RefCursor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360244/how-to-call-an-oracle-function-with-a-ref-cursor-as-out-parameter-from-c

Comment: by using OracleParameter explicitly then it works, but I have to use menuParam.DbType = DbType.String; like thing to make it generic, but there is no option like Cursor inthis enum

Comment: @Nits - just remove the second param as it's created automatically and called cur_OUT.  See here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37079/Returning-Multiple-Ref-Cursors-from-Oracle-using-D

Comment: this give me error saying mismatch in number of parameter calling the stored proc..

Comment: hmmm... See if you can discover the param and reverse engineer it.  `Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand dbCommand = b.GetStoredProcCommand( "MyPLSQLfunction");
db.DiscoverParameters( dbCommand );`